# BrowserMob Proxy Questions

Tags: java, selenium, browsermob-proxy

Is anyone familiar with using BrowserMob Proxy? I need some help.

> https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/blob/master/README.md

My goal is to try to use BrowserMob Proxy to detect that certain events are fired in the Network Tab. Any idea how to do this?

The language is in Java and I am using the Selenium Grid framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code you can get the HAR archive.

```
BrowserMobProxy proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
proxy.start(0);
HashSet<CaptureType> enable = new HashSet<CaptureType>();
enable.add(CaptureType.REQUEST_HEADERS);
enable.add(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT);
enable.add(CaptureType.RESPONSE_HEADERS);
proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(enable);
HashSet<CaptureType> disable = new HashSet<CaptureType>();
disable.add(CaptureType.REQUEST_COOKIES);
disable.add(CaptureType.RESPONSE_COOKIES);
proxy.disableHarCaptureTypes(disable);

//get the Selenium proxy object
Proxy selProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);

capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, selProxy);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS,true);

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(),profile,capabilities);


driver.get(url);

Har har = proxy.getHar();
```

Then explore the har object entries as you need

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming you ran script and got output in HAR format, upload at http://pcapperf.appspot.com/
2. You will see the output like http://pcapperf.appspot.com/harviewer/index.html?path=examples/en-wikipedia-org.har

Sample Code just for reference in Java (please change at your need)

```
package com.selenium.performancetest;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.browsermob.core.har.Har;
import org.browsermob.proxy.ProxyServer;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class PerfTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

String strFilePath = "";

// start the proxy
ProxyServer server = new ProxyServer(4444);
server.start();
//captures the moouse movements and navigations
server.setCaptureHeaders(true);
server.setCaptureContent(true);

// get the Selenium proxy object
Proxy proxy = server.seleniumProxy();

// configure it as a desired capability
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

// start the browser up
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

// create a new HAR with the label "apple.com"
server.newHar("assertselenium.com");

// open yahoo.com
driver.get("http://assertselenium.com");

driver.get("http://assertselenium.com/2012/10/30/transformation-from-manual-tester-to-a-selenium-webdriver-automation-specialist/");

// get the HAR data
Har har = server.getHar();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);
har.writeTo(fos);
server.stop();
driver.quit();

}

}
```

[Reference](http://www.assertselenium.com/browsermob-proxy/performance-data-collection-using-browsermob-proxy-and-selenium/)